# Prove or disprove: 'Island' of compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've been trying to prove something, and this seems to be getting in the way:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact. Then $X$ is bounded, and let $k \in (\inf X, \sup X)$ such that $k \notin X$. Then is the set $X' = \{x: x \in X, x>k \}$ closed?

Intuitively the answer appears to be a yes, since the only closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ I've dealt with are unions of finite sets and closed intervals, and if this is the case then there doesn't appear to be any tangible way that $X'$ *isn't* either a union of closed intervals and finite sets.

I've tried proving that the complement of $X'$ is open and tried proving compactness using open covers, but have been unable to go anywhere. At the same time, splitting something like $[0,1]$ into $[0,a] \cup [a,1]$ and $[0,a] \cup (a,1]$ doesn't satisfy the condition, and so I haven't found a counterexample either.

Is there any proof/disproof for the above assertion?

Comment: The boundedness thing can be removed from the question and the answer is still yes: Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be closed and let $k \in (\sup X, \inf X)$ such that $k \notin X$. Then is the set $X' = \{x: x \in X, x>k \}$ closed? (Answer: yes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k \not\in X$, so that
$$
X' = \{x: x \in X, x>k \} = \{x: x \in X, x \ge k \}
 = X \cap [k, \infty)
$$
is the intersection of two closed sets, and therefore closed.

It suffices that $X$ is a closed set. If $X$ is compact then $X'$ is a closed subset of $X$ and therefore compact as well.

The condition $k \in (\inf X, \sup X)$ is not needed for this argument.

Comment: Yeah, the "boundedness" part of the question is irrelevant and can be removed.